# AngularJS - Binding 'click' to directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-click

I'm currently working on a simple module to display notifications to the user in the form of toasts, or popups, that appear in the lower right-hand corner of the screen. The following directive works great except I would prefer to

a) use `.bind` instead of `ng-click` to handle manual dismissing of a notification;

b) use `replace: true` help reduce some of the generated markup

```
toast.directive('toast', function() {
    return {
        link: function($scope, $element, $attrs, $location) {
            $scope.delayDismiss = function(index) {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $scope.dismiss(index);
                    $scope.$apply();
                }, 5000);
            }

            $scope.dismiss = function(index) {
                $scope.messages[index].dismissed = true;
            }

            $element.bind('click', function() {
                console.log('This never triggers');
            });
        },
        replace: true,
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<li ng-repeat="toast in messages" ng-click="dismiss($index)" ng-init="delayDismiss($index)" ng-if="!toast.dismissed">{{toast.sender}} says {{toast.message}}</li>'
    }
});
```

The problem is that, now, `$element` in my `link()` function refers to the generated Angular comment instead of the `<li>` resulting in the bound click event never triggering. Which doesn't make any sense to me.

Am I misunderstanding this whole directive thing?

Comment: "The problem is that, now, `$element` in my `link()` function refers to the generated Angular comment" is wrong. As expected, `$element` refers to the `<li>`. Can you provide a fiddle reproducing the problem? Notice that `replace: true` is a deprecated functionality since 1.3.0-beta.10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> a) use .bind instead of ng-click to handle manual dismissing of a notification;

By removing `ngRepeat` from your directive's template, you should be able to do this within the directive's `link` function.  However, **I would advise against doing this** if it is only a matter of preference on your part.

See the answer to [How do I “think in AngularJS” if I have a jQuery background?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15012542/818187) for more details as to why.

Your usage of [`ngRepeat`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) is causing the linked element to refer to the generated comment node instead of the `<li>`.

By moving the `ngRepeat` directive outside your directive's template, the behavior is closer to what you're expecting:

```html
<toast ng-repeat="toast in messages"></toast>
```

> b) use replace: true help reduce some of the generated markup

That's fine, although note that the angular 1.3 documentation mentions that [`replace` has been deprecated](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-replace-deprecated-will-be-removed-in-next-major-release-) and will be removed from the next major release.

---

To make the directive more "re-usable", I would move the logic for an individual `toast` into its own factory instead of trying to handle it on the `link` function of the directive.

I would also add a [`ngTransclude`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngTransclude) to the template `<li>` and `transclude: true` to the directive's definition.

**View**

```html
<ol>
  <toast ng-repeat="toast in messages">
    {{toast.sender}} says {{toast.message}}
  </toast>
</ol>
```

**Controller**

```js
controller("MainCtrl", function ($scope, $toast) {      
  $scope.addToast = function(message, sender, timeout) {
    $toast.add(message, sender, parseInt(timeout));
  };
})
```

**Directive**

```js
directive('toast', function() {
  return {
    replace: true,
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<li ng-click="toast.dismiss()" ng-transclude></li>',
    transclude: true
  }
})
```

**Factory**

```js
factory("$toast", function($rootScope, $timeout) {
  var messages = $rootScope.messages = [];
  var $toast = (function() {
    function $toast(message, sender, timeout) {
      var self = this;
      this.message = message;
      this.sender = sender;
      this.timeout = timeout || $toast.defaultTimeout;
      this.timer = $timeout(function() {
        self.dismiss();
      }, this.timeout);
    }
    $toast.prototype.dismiss = function() {
      if (this.timer) {
        $timeout.cancel(this.timer);
        this.timer = null;
      }
      var index = messages.indexOf(this);
      if (index !== -1) {
        messages.splice(index, 1);
      }
    };
    return $toast;
  })();
  $toast.defaultTimeout = 5000;
  $toast.add = function(message, sender, timeout) {
    messages.push(new $toast(message, sender, timeout));
    return $toast;
  };
  return $toast;
})
```

Here is a working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/52JiHWi2jgloIyDst74I?p=preview

Comment: This is a far better answer than I ever expected! I suspect I will be referencing this whenever I'm thinking about how to structure a new component. Thank you so much!